# is user disable javascript in browser then how to run react app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Suppose user disable his/her JavaScript on browser then How to run react website or project on system

According to me its not running because it is a library of the javascript and without javascript it will not work on the browser.

Comment: Correct. If the user disables JS, and JS-based frameworks will not function.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to some how solve your issue is Server Side Rendering technology. The React app will be rendered on the server and then sent to the client side with HTML. So even without JS your user will be able to see some content.

However, it will not be interactive because interactivity requires JS.

If this answer is OK to you - give a look to the [Next.JS](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages) - it's React based framework with SSR support out of the box

But in general, React (as well as Angular, or Vue) are not working without the JavaScript.